# converting Excel to Password Protected PDF by using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, pdf

Im using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to convert from Excel to Pdf, and I done It, Now i Want To Make it password protected Pdf whthout using any third party dll.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: thanks for your Response mr. Sand , But i am Not Expected any One To Solve My Problem, I am Asking that , By Using this dll   is it possible to make protection..,thats it...

Comment: Then you need to rephrase the question and the other thing please understand that SO is a code based helping site so the community expect to see your code or the commitment you have made to solve the problem. If you just ask something like this they won't going to take it much seriously,